# Eclipse:Photon -- No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:// --- but only when 'calling' the java class

Tags: sql-server, jsp, jar, include

This one has me perplexed. I've rebuild everything from the ground up to narrow the problem, and it seems I simply can't call my static function that does JDBC calls from outside my class. When the class is run by itself it's fine, but when called statically I get the dreaded "No suitable driver found".

I've tried:

- rebuilding my virtual Tomcat Server
- different versions of the JARs (7,8,9) mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre7.jar -> jre9.jar
- different "import" or "build path/libraries" settings
- different versions of JRE (1.8 & 10)
- placed the JAR directly into my workspace.../.../...wtpwebapps/APP/WEB-INF/lib
- a standalone JAVA Package (works fine) -vs- Dynamic Web Package (fails)
- rebuilt the Class piece-by-piece, and summarized below

When the class runs on it's own via MAIN(), it's all good. But when it's called from another class, or a JSP it can't handle it.

**My Test Class**:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DB_TEST {
    private static String SQL_URL  = "jdbc:sqlserver://HostIP:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB";
    private static String SQL_User = "RO-User";
    private static String SQL_Pass = "RO-Pass";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getCurrentUsers());
    }
    public static String getCurrentUsers() {
          String sOut = "";
          Connection con = null;
          Statement stmt = null;
          ResultSet rs = null;
          try {
              con = DriverManager.getConnection(SQL_URL, SQL_User, SQL_Pass);
              String SQL = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
              stmt = con.createStatement();
              rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
              while (rs.next()) {
                  sOut += (rs.getString("User_GUID"))+"\n";
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
             if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
             if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
             if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
          }
          return sOut;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
AB6C77C9-1EC5-498A-8ED1-1AF8487B8CC8
456F75B3-5E3D-475C-B26D-218D9D9E04C2
AA101A7C-27B1-4F05-B12D-3A18A062986F
5915D156-DB0D-4CCA-9A65-601117649DC1
935DB225-39B8-4561-A4B9-702090323312
6BC1F025-6173-4634-90B8-9182673523B3
7B86E02F-AB57-4158-8586-B200C2B7D851
```

**My Connection String looks like**: `"jdbc:sqlserver://HostIP:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB"`

**My Test Servlet**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/DB_Call_Test")
public class DB_Call_Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append( DB_TEST.getCurrentUsers() );
    }
}
```

**My Test JSP**:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.List" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Why does this fail?</title>
</head>
<body>
Current Usssers:<br/>
<%= DB_TEST.getCurrentUsers()  %>
</body>
</html>
```

**On-going Error - from JSP or sister Class**:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://HostIP:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DB_TEST.getCurrentUsers(DB_TEST.java:41)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So. Turns out. Even under the latest JDK/JRE/Tomcat/JARs, Tomcat still needs the deprecated *Class.forName()* statement after all. I tried so many things to get these darn drivers to load, including standing up JNDI definitions. Which at first I thought was the solution.

I've since backed off everything except:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Driver.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
import java.util.*;
...
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"));
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://HostIP:1433;databaseName=TEST_DB", <SQL_User>, <SQL_Pass>);
```

I did notice that a lot of documentation shows the wrong DriverName for SQL Server (v9.jar). They all say : *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver*, but should be ...*jdbc.**SQLServerDriver***. I figured that out just by opening the JAR and finding it myself.